# yii2 REST Api file upload using PUT

Tags: php, rest, yii2

I am trying to add a REST api in Yii2 to be used by mobile applications to upload image/audio file. I am trying to use PUT method to get the image/file data from the http form-data, but for some reason the fopen("php://input", "r"); returns empty stream. I tried the code as give in this sample http://www.php.net/m...put-method.php.

```
<?php
/* PUT data comes in on the stdin stream */
$putdata = fopen("php://input", "r");

/* Open a file for writing */
$fp = fopen("myputfile.ext", "w");

/* Read the data 1 KB at a time
   and write to the file */
while ($data = fread($putdata, 1024))
  fwrite($fp, $data);

/* Close the streams */
fclose($fp);
fclose($putdata);
?>
```

Meanwhile, using POST method works though. Using the following code for POST

```
$putdata = fopen($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], "r");
        $filename = $this->documentPath.uniqid().'.jpg';
        /* Open a file for writing */
        $fp = fopen($filename, "w");

        /* Read the data 1 KB at a time
           and write to the file */
        while ($data = fread($putdata, 1024))
          fwrite($fp, $data);

        /* Close the streams */
        fclose($fp);
        fclose($putdata);
```

Comment: did you find solution?

Comment: nope, i used post for now

Comment: with REST? If yes how?

Comment: use the above code that I posted for the POST(the second block). I basically put that code in actionUpload method in my rest api controller class.

Comment: if not secret, can you share the view/controller code for rest (only for upload)? Am not that far in Yii2 rest!

Comment: Here you go. https://gist.github.com/appcodr/ff02301b259488a69710. For testing you can use postman client(chrome extension) and then in the URL params add a "data" variable for filename and choose a photo to upload

Comment: thanks. I use restclient for firefox

Answer (score 6):

Since version 2.0.10, a built-in mechanism has appeared that allows you to use PUT with formData: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-multipartformdataparser

So, at first you need to add parser to config file

```
return [
    'components' => [
        'request' => [
            'parsers' => [
                'multipart/form-data' => 'yii\web\MultipartFormDataParser'
            ],
        ],
        // ...
    ],
    // ...
];
```

Next - execute `getBodyParams` to populate $_FILES. This should be executed **before** requesting of any file.

```
$restRequestData = Yii::$app->request->getBodyParams();
```

And then files became available with general methods:

```
$file = UploadedFile::getInstancesByName('photo');
```

Comment: I did not know about that parser. Thanks you.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you send PUT with curl:

```
curl -X PUT -d 'BLABLABLA' http://localhost/upload
```

Then disable csrf validation in your upload controller:

```
\yii::$app->request->enableCsrfValidation = false;
```

Here's an example upload controller action using your code:

```
public function actionIndex()
{
   \yii::$app->request->enableCsrfValidation = false;
   $putdata = fopen("php://input", "r");
   // make sure that you have /web/upload directory (writeable) 
   // for this to work
   $path = \yii::getAlias('@webroot')."/upload/myputfile.ext";

   $fp = fopen($path, "w");

   while ($data = fread($putdata, 1024))
      fwrite($fp, $data);

   /* Close the streams */
   fclose($fp);
   fclose($putdata);
```

}

Check the upload:

```
$ cat /path/to/webroot/upload/myputfile.ext
BLABLABLA
```